# R - Mean of columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r

Good evening, I'd just like to start off by saying I'm the biggest newbie to coding. I've gone through so many tutorials just to try and make a simple football/soccer data frame.

I now currently have something like this;

```
Home team | Away Team | Home Goals | Away Goals
M.United    Liverpool      0             0
```

I have that for all results of the season so far. 
What i'd like to do is get the mean of home goals column, and away goals column.

Also, if it's do-able, I'd like to filter a specific team and see what their average goals are at home, and their average goals conceded at home are, etc.

Thanks in advance, and apologies for my total utter noobism.

Jay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For obtaining `mean` Try,

`summary(your_data_frame_name)`, it will give you basic statistics of each column including `Home.Goals`.

OR to just get mean of a column,

`mean(your_data_frame_name$Home.Goals)`

To filter specific team, look into `select` function. You can do:

`M_united_home <- subset(your_data_frame_name, Home.team == M.united)`

Then you can use this data frame to answer any more queries about Man united. If you want to do more, also look into `dplyr` package.

Comment: Many thanks! Just the sort of thing I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dplyr package with something like:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  summarise(mean_home = mean(home_goals), mean_away = mean(away_goals))
```

*(I am pretty sure that will work, but one thing that is great to do is to create a reproducible example so I can run your code to double check, for example I am not exactly sure what your variables names / data set names are, and I am not able to run your code as it is, a great resource for this is the [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) package).*